# R boxplot long names out of the plot area

Tags: r, label, boxplot

My boxplot names are long and making it vertical chop these names.  How can I avoid the names/labels of boxplot going out of the plot area?

```
dat <- data.frame(values = rnorm(100), group = gl(2, 50))
levels(dat$group) <- c("reallyreallylonglabel", 
                       "anevenlooooooooooooongerlabel")
boxplot(values ~ group, data = dat,  las = 3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the bottom margin using the par() function.

```
par(mar=c(14, 3, 1, 1))
boxplot(values ~ group, data=dat, las=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ggplot library the labels should come out nicely.
library(ggplot2)

```
dat <- data.frame(values = rnorm(100), group = gl(2, 50))
levels(dat$group) <- c("reallyreallylonglabel", 
                       "anevenlooooooooooooongerlabel")


ggplot(dat, aes(factor(group),values)) + stat_boxplot()
```